# Play 2.4: intercept and modify response body

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

According to [play documentation](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaActionsComposition#Custom-action-builders) this is what a custom action should look like:

```
object CustomAction extends ActionBuilder[Request] {
    def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: Request[A] => Future[Result]): Future[Result] = {
        block(request)
    }
}
```

But say if I wanted to append "foo" to every response body, how do I do that? Obviously below doesn't work:

```
block.andThen(result => result.map(r => r.body.toString + "foo")).apply(request)
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** Something worth mentioning is that this action would be mostly used as asynchronous in the controller:

```
def test = CustomAction.async {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to take the `Enumerator[Array[Byte]]` from the `Result` body and feed it to an iteratee to actually consume the result body before you can modify it.  So a simple iteratee that consumes the result body and converts to a String might look like:

```
block.apply(request).flatMap { res =>
  Iteratee.flatten(res.body |>> Iteratee.consume[Array[Byte]]()).run.map { byteArray =>
    val bodyStr = new String(byteArray.map(_.toChar))
    Ok(bodyStr + "foo")
  }
}
```

I used `flatMap` as the result of running `Iteratee.flatten` is a `Future[T]`. Check out https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Enumerators for more details on how to work with Enumerators/Iteratees.

Comment: Thanks, this is working, however there's one problem - the solution defaults to `Ok` and will override other response types such as `BadRequest`

Comment: My example was meant to be simple, to make it more complete you would need to read the result status from the ResponseHeader and handle your new result appropriately