# Play Framework: How to modify the response body without blocking?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, servlet-filters, playframework-2.5

I'm cutting my teeth on Play using the book [Reactive Web Applications: Covers Play, Akka, and Reactive Streams](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/163343009X). Chapter 4, among other things, teaches how to write a filter, but the code shown in the book doesn't compile, because in Play 2.4.x, `Result.body` used to be `Enumerator[Array[Byte]]` and in 2.5.x it is `play.api.http.HttpEntity`.

My version of the filter is as below:

```
class ScoreFilter @Inject()(implicit val mat: Materializer, ec: ExecutionContext) extends Filter {
  override def apply(nextFilter: (RequestHeader) => Future[Result])(rh: RequestHeader) =
    nextFilter(rh).map { result =>
      if (result.header.status == OK || result.header.status == NOT_ACCEPTABLE) {
        val correct = result.session(rh).get("correct").getOrElse(0)
        val wrong = result.session(rh).get("wrong").getOrElse(0)

        val score = s"\nYour current score is: $correct correct " +
          s"answers and $wrong wrong answers"

        val contentType = result.body.contentType
        val scoreByteString = ByteString(score.getBytes(UTF_8))
        val maybeNewBody = result.body.consumeData.map(_.concat(scoreByteString))

        import scala.concurrent.duration._
        val newBody = Await.result(maybeNewBody, 10 seconds)

        result.copy(body = Strict(newBody, contentType))
      } else {
        result
      }
    }
}
```

In the book:

```
// result.body returns a play.api.http.HttpEntity which doesn't have an andThen method
val newBody = result.body andThen Enumerator(score.getBytes(UTF_8))
result.copy(body = newBody)
```

As you can see, my version of the filter works but it blocks on the future. I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this without blocking?

P.S.: Before dismissing my question as duplicate, please be aware that I've read all of the following threads and they convert the response body into a string, which isn't what I want.

[Scala play http filters: how to find the request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822416/scala-play-http-filters-how-to-find-the-request-body)

[Play framework filter that modifies json request and response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645034/play-framework-filter-that-modifies-json-request-and-response)

[Play 2.4: intercept and modify response body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130551/play-2-4-intercept-and-modify-response-body)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to avoid `Await.result`, you can do:

```
nextFilter(rh).flatMap { result =>
  ...
  maybeNewBody map { newBody =>
    result.copy(body = Strict(newBody, contentType))
  }
} else Future.successful(result)
```

(note the change of `map` to `flatMap`)

Comment: That works but I'm having to change the body to `Strict`. I'm curious if that can be avoided using `Iteratees` and `Enumerators`?

Comment: the only options for `HttpEntity` are `Strict`, `Streamed`, and `Chunked`. according to the documentation, `Strict` is what you want here since you have the content in memory: https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.2/api/java/play/http/HttpEntity.html

Comment: That's what I thought too, however, I'm wondering if in the filter we will always know the type of the body. As you said, there are 3.
I emailed the author Manuel Bernhardt. Will post here if he provides an alternative. Meanwhile, I'll accept your answer.